# Spring Boot 2 includes Stacktrace when no Trace Parameter is given

Tags: spring-boot

after having upgraded from Spring Boot 1.5.12 to 2.0.1, the system includes a stacktrace in the case of an error even when the trace parameter "trace" is not specified in the URL (or wrongly specified with a invalid value).

I have configured

server.error.include-stacktrace=on-trace-param

in my application.properties.

When I call my application, that throws an error, via http://localhost/myApp the system returns a filled trace.

When I call it via http://localhost/myApp?trace=false it doesn't.

When I call it via http://localhost/myApp?trace=hugo it does and with http://localhost/myApp?trace=true also.

This was not the case under Spring Boot 1. There, the system did include a stack trace only when one specified trace=true, which is the expected behavior.

Was this behavior changed from version 1 to 2?

Ciao, Michael

Answer (score 1):

this is the code in springboot2.0.3

```
protected boolean getTraceParameter(HttpServletRequest request) {
    String parameter = request.getParameter("trace");
    return !"false".equalsIgnoreCase(parameter);
}
```

in springboot2.1

```
protected boolean getTraceParameter(HttpServletRequest request) {
    String parameter = request.getParameter("trace");
    if (parameter == null) {
        return false;
    }
    return !"false".equalsIgnoreCase(parameter);
}
```

upgrade the springboot version to 2.1 to resolve the problem

Comment: this does not solve the problem because in this case also trace=hugo would trace in this way.

I would expect that only trace=true enables the trace, and this is also how the system worked under Spring 1, i.e.

return "true".equalsIgnoreCase(parameter);

would be compatible.

Comment: Why would `getTraceParameter` return `true` when it is set to `false`!?!?